# Custom command in right-click menu not working

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have added, via the registry, a right click menu option for all filetypes which is supposed to get the MD5 checksum for a file.

> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*\shell\Checksum - Default: Get Checksum

and

> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*\shell\Checksum\command - Default: checksum.cmd "%1"

checksum.cmd simply clears the screen, calls fciv.exe using %1 and then pauses.

Unfortunately, whilst the option "Get Checksum" appears correctly in the right click menu, it doesn't perform the right action when clicked. When I click it an "Open With" dialog opens, which is of course not what I want.

Both checksum.cmd and fciv.exe are in the PATH.

checksum.cmd:

```
@echo off
cls
fciv.exe %1
pause
```

Anybody know what's going on?

Comment: can you show us the checksum.cmd content? do you pass %1 parameter correctly to fciv.exe ?

Comment: You may have to make the Checksum\command something like default: `cmd.exe /C checksum.cmd "%1"`.

Comment: I've edited my OP to include checksum.cmd contents.

Comment: Thanks Martineau, I'll try that. EDIT: It worked! Thanks. If you post that as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @martineau Post your answer.
-Luke you need to use @ sign to call someone i think. Otherwise he might no know you are talking to him.

Comment: @mnmnc: You're correct about needing the @ sign, however I was alerted by your comment and now all is well -- thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to execute the .cmd file you need to invoke the Windows command shell and tell it to interpret the script. To set this up in the registry, change the data for the (Default) value of the command key to `cmd.exe` as shown:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Checksum\command - Default: cmd.exe /C checsum.cmd "%1"
```

BTW, you could replace the `pause` command in your script with something that would automatically wait for a specified amount of time -- long enough for you to read the output -- before continuing on and doing other things or allowing the window to disappear. For example to pause for 5 seconds, you could use:

```
ping 1.0.0.0 -n 1 -w 5000 >nul
```

The value following the `-w` argument gives the amount of time in milliseconds to wait.